# How to prove $\sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{\ln^2 k}{k^2}<2-\frac{\ln^2 n}{n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $n\geq 2.$
Prove
$$\sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{\ln^2 k}{k^2}<2-\frac{\ln^2 n}{n}$$
Maybe there is a simple solution?

Comment: Where is what you tried?

Comment: I try by induction, but i can't solve this

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Integration by parts gives
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{\log(t)^2}{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t
&=-\frac{\log(t)^2}{t}+2\int\frac{\log(t)}{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=-\frac{\log(t)^2}{t}-2\frac{\log(t)}t+2\int\frac1{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=C-\frac{\log(t)^2+2\log(t)+2}t
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt at proving this by induction.

Clearly, the inequality is true for $k=2$. Assume that the inequality is true for $k=n-1$ for $n > 2$. We will prove that it is true for $k=n$. Here is the inequality for $k=n-1$:

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} \frac{\ln^2k}{k^2} < 2-\frac{\ln^2(n-1)}{n-1}$$

Here is the inequality for $k=n$:

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} \frac{\ln^2k}{k^2}+\frac{\ln^2n}{n^2} < 2-\frac{\ln^2(n-1)}{n-1}+\frac{\ln^2(n-1)}{n-1}-\frac{\ln^2n}{n}$$

Thus, if we can prove $\frac{\ln^2n}{n^2}<\frac{\ln^2(n-1)}{n-1}-\frac{\ln^2n}{n}$, we can combine it with the inequality from $k=n-1$ to prove the inequality for $k=n$.

Now, this is where I get stuck. The inequality [seems to be true after graphing the two functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJXQw.png), but I don't know how to actually prove it. Hopefully, though, this will help you a little bit.

Comment: The denominator on the right hand side is $n$, not $n^2$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Thanks for the catch. I think I've fixed my answer above correctly.

Comment: https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Lagrange%27s_Mean_Value_Theorem for $\frac{\ln^2n}{n^2}<\frac{\ln^2(n-1)}{n-1}-\frac{\ln^2n}{n}$ help

Comment: How does the mean value theorem help solve this inequality?

Comment: $\frac{\ln^2n}{n^2}<\frac{\ln^2(n-1)}{n-1}-\frac{\ln^2n}{n}$ look at if n=1000,http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B%5Cln%5E2+1000000%7D%7B1000000%5E2%7D%3C%5Cfrac%7B%5Cln%5E2+(1000000-1)%7D%7B1000000-1%7D-%5Cfrac%7B%5Cln%5E2+1000000%7D%7B1000000%7D

Comment: Oh...I guess you'll have to go the integration way, then.